# Pressing JButton instead of keyboard

Tags: java, events, key, jbutton, imagej

I´m working on a project with Java and ImageJ.
I have a slight problem making the following to work properly:

I have a JButton t. When I click on t, it should be the same as if I just pressed "T" on the keyboard.
Reason is (for those of you familiar with ImageJ) when you drag out a ROI in ImageJ and press the "T" Button on your keyboard, it opens the Region Manager and add the freshly dragged out ROI to the Manager.
So instead of coding it to the point, where it adds the ROI to the Region Manager when I click on t (it´s a bit too complex for me), the t button should perform somehow a keyboard event that presses "T" for me, when I click on the t JButton.

Comment: Count me among those who are still confused, and so if you don't get a decent answer soon, consider clarifying your question a bit and showing code. Please look at [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for good suggestions. Also, you'll probably want to get rid of the line `"Please don't make your coding too complex..."`. 1) This site is for answering questions, not getting code, and 2) this site is staffed by volunteers, so you'll not want to put restrictions on any answers you might get. If anything confuses you in answers or comments, just ask.

Comment: *"Please don´t make your coding too complex.."*  Please ask a question.  For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

No idea what ImageJ is, but since you are using a `JButton` I would guess it is based on `Swing`. In Swing you would use [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for this. That is you create an `Action` that can be used when you click the button or use the keyboard.

Start with the Action:

```
Action tAction = new AbstractAction()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerford(ActionEvent e)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Use a JButton:

```
JButton button = new JButton( tAction );
button.setText("some action");
```

Use Key Bindings:

```
button.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("T"), "tAction");
button.getActionMap().put("tAction", tAction);
```

Comment: thanks, but this does´t work. Do I have to put it in different classes? Because when I implemented the Action and afterwards I implement the keybindings, how will the keybings know that they have to perform a code, that´s written above them? Sorry for my poor english

Comment: @MaxRoth, `how will the keybings know that they have to perform a code,` - because you used the InputMap/ActionMap to bind a KeyStroke to an Action. In the example above the `tAction` is bound to the the `T KeyStroke`.

Comment: `when I click on the Button that it´s like I pressed the "T" on my keyboard.` - check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23375276/attaching-a-single-action-listener-to-all-buttons/23375436#23375436 for a complete example.