# How to reuse actionListener's method for key-press when using a JButton?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, windowbuilder

I am creating a calculator GUI application in Java . I have implemented the calculator for presses on the JButtons with the mouse. I want to listen to numpad presses as well for the numbers but I don't want to re-create the method in the ActionListener.

For example this is how I implement listenOne when pressed on the JButton.

```
class ListentoOne implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg) {

            if(floating)
                aftDec+="1";

            else if(!operanD)
                ans=(ans*10)+1;

            else
            operand=(operand*10)+1;

            screen.setText(output+="1");

            }
}
```

and in the constructor of the panel class I constructed the JButton this way:

```
one=new JButton("1");
one.addActionListener(new ListentoOne());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use [Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for this, not a `KeyListener`. Of course there are multiple ways of achieving this with Key Bindings, but in my example I made  new class that just calls `doClick()` on the button if you press `1`.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

public class Example {

    public Example() {

        JLabel label = new JLabel("0");
        ShortCutButton button = new ShortCutButton("1", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_1, 0));
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                label.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(label.getText()) + 1));
            }
        });
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.add(button);
        frame.add(label);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Example();
            }
        });
    }

    public class ShortCutButton extends JButton {
        public ShortCutButton(String text, KeyStroke keyStroke) {
            setText(text);
            getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(keyStroke, "42");
            getActionMap().put("42", new AbstractAction() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    doClick();
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This is the best answer of the bunch

Answer (score 0):

```
for(ActionListener a: button.getActionListeners()) {
    a.actionPerformed(yourActionEvent);
}
```

Comment: elaborate on your answer

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Calculator Panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23375276/attaching-a-single-action-listener-to-all-buttons/23375436#23375436) example.

It shows how you can share a single ActionListener for all your buttons. The example also uses KeyBindings so that you can either click on the button or type the number displayed on the button to invoke the Action.