# Java swing: Simulate buttonClick animation with KeyBind

Tags: java, swing, audio

I'm making a drum app and I've used KeyBindings so I can trigger the sounds of the drums using the keyboard.

Let's say for example the key trigger for my `btnBassDrm` is `'B'`. What I want to do is when I press  `'B'` the animation of a button being pressed in my `btnBassDrum(like in mouseClicked event)` will also trigger. So in effect, it really looks like you're playing drums.

Any ideas on how I could make this possibe? Thanks guys! :)

MORE INFO:

This is how I use key bindings:

I have a class named KeyBind which has 6 methods of return type Action

```
public static Action getSnareAction(){
        Action snareAction = new AbstractAction(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                 try{
                    music=new FileInputStream(new File(Sound.snareSound));
                    AudioStream audios=new AudioStream(music);
                    AudioPlayer.player.start(audios);
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex.getLocalizedMessage());
                    }
            }
        };

        return snareAction;
    }
```

then in my Mainform I have 6 methods that does the binding also.

```
public void snareActionKeyBind(){
        snareDrumAction = KeyBind.getSnareAction();

        InputMap inputMap = btnSnareDrum.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("E"), "hitSnareDrum");
        btnSnareDrum.getActionMap().put("hitSnareDrum", snareDrumAction);
    }
```

then I call these 6 methods in the constructor of the Mainform

```
public FreePlayForm() {
        initComponents();

        bassActionKeyBind();
        crashActionKeyBind();
        snareActionKeyBind();
        hihatActionKeyBind();
        rackTomActionKeyBind();
        floorTomActionKeyBind();

    }
```

this is how my form looks like:
[image]

It just looks like that whenever I'm hitting the keys and playing or just doing nothing. It does not have that "being pressed down" animation like when you click it. That's my goal right now to have that "being pressed down animation" when you hit the keys.

Comment: What have you got at the moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an `Action`. The Action can be used as the ActionListener of the button and can be used in the Key Bindings for the given KeyStroke.

From the Swing tutorial you can read sections on:

1. [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html)
2. [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

You can check out: [Attaching A Single Action Listener To All Buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23375276/attaching-a-single-action-listener-to-all-buttons/23375436#23375436) for an example with Actions and Key Bindings.

Edit:

> That's my goal right now to have that "being pressed down animation" when you hit the keys.

Then in the Action for the Key Binding you need to invoke doClick() on the related button, instead of sharing the Action. So for each button you need 2 Actions

1. one the play the sound
2. the other to do the click on the button which in turn will play the sound

Comment: doClick simulates mouseClicked right? somehow the response of the sound became slower there's a bit of delay before the sound actually triggers when I press the key assigned

Comment: @Andre, which doClick() method did you use, the one that takes a parameter of the one that doesn't?

Comment: I tried doClick(30) and it's just the right speed. Thank you! So I gotta delete my KeyBind class now eh? Since I will be putting the action that plays the sound on their respective buttonClicked events, my KeyBind class has no use now.