# Action performed not changing text

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have an `actionPerformed` and one of the if/else is that if the user presses the "A" key, it will set the text to something different. Instead of setting the text after pressing "A", the program skips setting the text and moves down to the if statement below. My question is, how can I have my program set the text before my if statement? My code is below, thanks!

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ATMProject extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private JPanel mainPanel = null;
    private JPanel btnPanel = null;
    private JPanel userBtns = null;
    private JTextArea textArea = null;
    private JPanel keyPanel = null;
    private JTextField numField = null;
    private JPanel numpadPanel = null;
    private JButton[] userButtons = null;
    private JButton[] keypadButtons = null;
    private String[] btnPanelbtns = { "A", "B", "C" };
    private String[] numpadPanelbtns = { "7", "8", "9", "4", "5", "6", "1", "2", "3", "0", ".", "CE" };
    private boolean isuserButtonPressed = false;
    private boolean isAccEntered = true;
    private FileReader file = null;
    private String custAcc;
    private String custPin;
    private String userInputAcc;
    private String userInputPin;

    public ATMProject() {
        super();
        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(mainPanel);

        btnPanel = new JPanel();
        btnPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
        this.add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);

        textArea = new JTextArea();
        this.add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        keyPanel = new JPanel();
        keyPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(keyPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);

        numpadPanel = new JPanel();
        numpadPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 3));
        keyPanel.add(numpadPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        numField = new JTextField();
        keyPanel.add(numField, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        userButtons = new JButton[btnPanelbtns.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < userButtons.length; i++) {
            userButtons[i] = new JButton(btnPanelbtns[i]);
            userButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
            btnPanel.add(userButtons[i]);
        }

        keypadButtons = new JButton[numpadPanelbtns.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < numpadPanelbtns.length; i++) {
            keypadButtons[i] = new JButton(numpadPanelbtns[i]);
            keypadButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
            numpadPanel.add(keypadButtons[i]);
        }

        textArea.setText("Enter customer number: --> \nPress A when done \nA = OK");
        userInputAcc = numField.getText();

        // reading
        try {
            file = new FileReader("ConfidentialCustInfo.txt");
            Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
            custAcc = input.next();
            custPin = input.next();
            System.out.println(custAcc);
            System.out.println(custPin);
            input.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("CE")) {
            numField.setText("");
        } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("1")) {
            numField.setText(numField.getText() + "1");
        } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("2")) {
            numField.setText(numField.getText() + "2");
        } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("3")) {
            numField.setText(numField.getText() + "3");
        } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("4")) {
            numField.setText(numField.getText() + "4");
        } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("5")) {
            numField.setText(numField.getText() + "5");
        } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("6")) {
            numField.setText(numField.getText() + "6");
        } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("7")) {
            numField.setText(numField.getText() + "7");
        } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("8")) {
            numField.setText(numField.getText() + "8");
        } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("9")) {
            numField.setText(numField.getText() + "9");
        } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("A")) {
            if (numField.getText().isEmpty()) {
                textArea.setText("error");
            } else {
                numField.setText("");
                textArea.setText("Enter PIN: \n A = OK");
                userInputPin = (numField.getText());

            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyFrame mf = new MyFrame();
    }

}
```

Comment: Typically you would use a JOptionPane to prompt the user for information. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more information and examples. Don't use nested if/else statements in a listener. Each button should have its own listener. Buttons with common functionality can share listener (ie the numberic button). See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23375276/attaching-a-single-action-listener-to-all-buttons/23375436#23375436 for an example of this approach.

Answer (score 2):

You need to give your program a state variable, something that will tell it what state it's on, and then allow the listener to respond differently depending on that state.

For instance you can give it a boolean variable or variables, something like

```
private boolean enteringAcctNumber = true;
```

and then place an if block in your ActionListener that checks this boolean and responds appropriately.

For example

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class ATMProj2 extends JPanel {
    private static final int COLS = 30;
    private static final String ACCOUNT_PROMPT = "Enter Account Number";
    protected static final String ENTER_PIN = "Account number accepted. Enter PIN";
    protected static final String PIN_ACCEPTED = "PIN has been accepted. Have fun.";
    private boolean enteringAcctNumber = true;
    private JTextField textField = new JTextField(COLS);
    private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(6, COLS);
    private JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");

    public ATMProj2() {
        textArea.setText(ACCOUNT_PROMPT);
        textArea.setFocusable(false); // so user can't mess with it
        okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // test state variable, and base behavior on its state
                if (enteringAcctNumber) {
                    textArea.setText(ENTER_PIN);
                    textField.setText("");
                    enteringAcctNumber = false; // ok now not entering account
                } else {
                    textArea.setText(PIN_ACCEPTED);
                }
            }
        });

        JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
        btnPanel.add(okButton);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(textField, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(new JScrollPane(textArea), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        ATMProj2 mainPanel = new ATMProj2();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ATMProj2");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            createAndShowGui();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: So essentially I am creating a boolean to check and make sure that an account number was entered, and if it was, continue onto the text setting. Or else, display an error.

Comment: @Blastoize34: or several booleans depending on the state, or it doesn't have to be a boolean. I often use enums for state fields. See edit to answer.

Comment: Even after adding the boolean, it still isn't working. `else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("A")) {
   if (isAccEntered) {
    textArea.setText("");
    textArea.setText("Enter PIN: \n A = OK");
    userInputPin = numField.getText();
    if (userInputPin.equals(custPin)) {
     textArea.setText("SUCCESS");
    } else {
     textArea.setText("fail");
    }
   }
  }`

Comment: I have isAccEntered set to true.

Comment: @Blastoize34: the logic should be simple to think through. Walk through your code in your head and it will fall into place. If still stuck, please edit your original question and post code there, since code in comments loses its formatting and is thus very difficult to read.

Comment: Edited, my problem is illustrated above.

Comment: After breaking my program down, and printing out the variables and such, the reason why it is not working is because the`.getText()` from the `numField` is not working. And the reason the comparison is not working is because the `numField` is returning null or 0 or something.

Answer (score 2):

This is a comment from your other posting:

> I see that when I use userInputAcc = numField.getText(); it is not getting the text from the JTextField(). I figured this out because I set the text of the JTextArea to userInputAcc and the screen went blank>

```
textArea.setText("Enter customer number: --> \nPress A when done \nA = OK");
userInputAcc = numField.getText();
```

Of course it is blank because the statement is executed when you build the GUI and the user hasn't had a chance to type anything in the text field yet. The frame isn't even visible when the above statement is executed.

This is easy to verify. Just change your code to:

```
userInputAcc = numField.getText();
System.out.println( "(" + userINputAcc + ")" );
```

This is basic debugging to display the value of the variable at the time you assign a value to the variable.

You can only get text from the text field when an event is generated and you write code to handle the event. So the `userInputAcc` variable will always be empty.

Also, why does your code still have the ugly nested if statement in the ActionListener?