# Userset Keybind For Java

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

So, I am making a application, when you click a button (jButton1) it prints "Hi" (for example)

Now, I also have a textbox. In the textbox you need to specify a key.

How do I make so when you press the key you specified, it runs jButton1.doClick()

UPDATE: This is a auto clicker. So, I have a boolean 
started
If I type k (out of the application) I want it to set the boolean started to true. If I type k again, and boolean started is true, set it to false.

Thank you so much!

UPDATE 2: I really need help! Why won't String code = `NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(nativeEvent.getKeyCode());
        if (code == AutoClickFrame.jTextField1.getText().toUpperCase())
        {
            System.out.println("Hello World!");
        }`
work?

Comment: So to clarify, the user types a letter, say `"k"`, and then the *next* time "k" is pressed, the button also gets pressed? And this happens even though the JTextField (note that Swing does not have "textboxes") still has focus?

Comment: And also, for this question, and most questions, it's always best for you to show what you've done so far, and to describe the fruits of your researches performed before asking the question. And it's usually expected that you have done some prior research before asking.

Comment: This is a auto clicker. So, I have a boolean 
started
If I type k (out of the application) I want it to set the boolean started to true. If I type k again, and boolean started is true, set it to false.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm completely ignorant in what an "auto clicker" is. Could you please tell me more about this? And are you desiring this GUI to capture key presses even if this application itself does not have system focus?

Comment: The auto clicker part really doesn't matter. I just want it to capture the key that is in jTextField1 even when its not in focus. Then, run the code System.out.println("Hello World");

Comment: Sorry, and I know that I keep asking questions, which is annoying, I know, but if I fully understand a question, I can fully answer it, but there are **two** focus issues here: 1) the JTextField focus. If the JTextField has focus, usually all key presses should go towards putting text into the JTextField. If your app does otherwise -- steals the key press and uses it to press a button, that's confusing, and 2) **application focus**. Does the application need to work even if it is not the current active application, as a "key logger" would work? If so, then ...

Comment: .... the best solution will likely not involve Java, but rather other languages and tools that are easier to work with in this situation.

Comment: Ok, so let's pretend I didn't ask for the out of focus part. How could I set a Keybind for the Key event? Like, instead of e.getKeyCode(2) Can I do e.getKeyCode(jTextField1)?

Comment: [How to get Strings/text out of JTextFields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html)

Comment: I'm thinking. String text = jTextField1.getText();  Then something like: if(KeyEvent.getKeyCode(text) = ???What do I do?){ System.out.println("Hello World!");}

Comment: See, I need to convert the text into a key code. Then check if that keycode is pressed. Then, if it is print something.

Comment: NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(nativeEvent.getKeyCode());
  if (code == AutoClickFrame.jTextField1.getText().toUpperCase())
  {
   System.out.println("Hello World!");
  }  won't work.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I make so when you press the key you specified, it runs jButton1.doClick()

You use `Key Bindings`. That is you map a KeyStroke to an Action. When the key is pressed the Action is invoked. The Action would also be used as the ActionListener of the button.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more information.

For a working example check out: [Attaching A Single Action Listener To All Buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23375276/attaching-a-single-action-listener-to-all-buttons/23375436#23375436)

Comment: Ok, so let's pretend I didn't ask for the out of focus part. How could I set a Keybind for the Key event? Like, instead of e.getKeyCode(2) Can I do e.getKeyCode(jTextField1)?

Comment: I don't understand your question. I gave you a link to the Swing tutorial which has a working example of using key bindings. All also gave you a link to another question with a working example. What part of those example don't you understand? Maybe I don't understand your requirement?

Comment: I am using jNatoveHook. So, I need to check if the key pressed matches the text in the textbox.

Comment: I'm wondering if this will work: String code =  NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(nativeEvent.getKeyCode());     jLabel1.setText(code);  if(code.equal‌​s(jTextField1.getTex‌​t.toUpperCase()){ System.out.println("It works!");} Giving this example, do you see what I'm trying to do? If you don't quite get it, what can I clarify? Thanks!

Comment: @We__Create, I have no idea what jNatoveHook is and I have no idea why you are using it. You have been given the Swing solution for binding a KeyStroke to an Action.

Comment: I found the solution. jNativeHook is a library that allows the application to see the keys being pressed without it focused.

Comment: What I wanted was to check what key is being pressed, and if that key matches the key in the textbox run something. I did this (code is the key char to a string) : if(code.equalsIgnoreCase(jTextField1.getText()){ System.out.println("Hello World!"); } I am going to make this better by using a toggle button, so when clicked, listen for a key then set that key to the text. So if someone has Ctrl they don't need to worry about the way it's typed