# Creating virtual number pad in java

Tags: java, swing, virtual-keyboard, jpasswordfield

I am developing a desktop application. In this application I have to use virtual keyboard/numberpad for login operations etc.

I've created a jframe like this:
[image]

and buttons' creation code is

```
numberButtons = new JButton[10];
    for(int i = 0; i < numberButtons.length; i++ ) {
        numberButtons[i] = new JButton(String.valueOf(i));
    numberButtons[i].setFont(new java.awt.Font("Open Sans", 0, 14));
    numberButtons[i].setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 50));

    numberButtons[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
        {
            numberButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
        numberPanel.add(numberButtons[i]);
    }
```

and action method is:

```
private void numberButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

    String currentPassword = ((JButton) evt.getSource()).getText();

    passwordField.requestFocus();
    passwordField.setText(passwordField.getText() + currentPassword);
    if (Arrays.equals(pass, passwordField.getPassword())) {
        System.out.println("Correct");
    }
}
```

but jpasswordfield's gettext method is dispatched. It isn't recommended to use. I have another idea to write actionperformed method for every button and use "KeyEvent.VK_" in each buttons' action. However, I don't think it's a proper way to do it. What would you recommend?

Comment: Each button should add a char to an array or list, what you're trying to do, is not generate a `String` of the password. You may need to insert content directly in the `JPasswordField`'s `Document`

Comment: Since I want to add a char to passwordfield when button is clicked, I needed to use 'passwordfield.settext' method which I needed to use string.

What is the other way to insert directly into JPasswordField's Document you mentioned?

Comment: No, you need to  use Document#insertString, inserting each character (as an individual String) into the Document

Answer (score 0):

You already used `passwordField.getPassword()`. This is the correct way to do this. The docs say that `getText` has been replaced by `getPassword`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html#getText()

To construct a String from the returned `char[]` use [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(char[])) constructor.

Comment: *"To construct a String from the returned char[]"* - that just defeats the purpose of not using `getText` in the first place

Comment: @Selim
You mean i should do something like that:
 `private void numberButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        
        passwordField.requestFocus();
        passwordField.setText(new String(passwordField.getPassword())+         ((JButton) evt.getSource()).getText());
        if(Arrays.equals(pass,passwordField.getPassword())){
            System.out.println("Correct");
        }
    }`

Comment: @Emre yes. However this will defeat the purpose of the "security" the `char[]` is supposed to give you as @MadProgrammer pointed out. In this case you can also replace `Arrays.equals` with `pass.equals(new String(passwordField.getPassword()))`

Answer (score 0):

Create a button class that encapsulates a JButton, the creation of a listener, and any other helpful features. Then use that class in substitution to the buttons creation code.

Answer (score 0):

> but jpasswordfield's gettext method is dispatched

Don't use setText(...) to reset the entire text.

Instead just add the character that was typed to the end of the text component. One way to do this is to use the `replaceSelection(...)` method of the text component.

Check out: [Attaching A Single Action Listener To All Buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23375276/attaching-a-single-action-listener-to-all-buttons/23375436#23375436) for a working example. Note the example will allow you to type the character or click on the button.