# Swing Keyboard Layout Input

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to create a keyboard layout using Swing in Java and so far I have been able to display a keyboard built up from a list and a loop however I now need to get the corresponding letter when a button has been pressed. So for example, I click Q then my output should print "Q".

GUI So Far:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIP5c.png]

I don't think I am able to alter my code to cater for this, rather I might need to find a workaround but just in case I am missing something, I thought I would ask here.

Here is my code so far:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;  

public class gui {  
    private final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Keyboard");
    private final JPanel keyboard = new JPanel();
    
    JTable table;
    JPanel pRow;
    JButton b;
    
    public static final String[][] key = {
        {"Q", "W", "E", "R", "T", "Y", "U", "I", "O", "P"},
        {"A", "S", "D", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "L", " "},
        {"Enter", "Z", "X", "C", "V", "B", "N", "M", "⌫"},
    };
    
    public gui() {
        keyboard.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        Insets zeroInset = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
        Font monospace = new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 12);

        GridBagConstraints cRow = new GridBagConstraints(), cButton = new GridBagConstraints();
        cRow.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;
        cButton.ipady = 21;

        for (int row = 0, i = 0; row < key.length; ++row) {
            pRow = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

            cRow.gridy = row;

            for (int col = 0; col < key[row].length; ++col, ++i) {

                switch (key[row][col]) {
                    case "Enter":       cButton.ipadx = 19; break;
                    case " ":       cButton.ipadx = 7; break;
                    default:
                        cButton.ipadx = 7;
                        cButton.insets = zeroInset;
                }

                b = new JButton(key[row][col]);
                b.setFont(monospace);
                b.setFocusable(false);
                b.addActionListener(e -> { System.out.println(); });
                pRow.add(b, cButton);
            }

            keyboard.add(pRow, cRow);
        }

        frame.add(keyboard);
    }
    
    public void launch() {
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(700, 700);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        gui ui = new gui();
        ui.launch();
    }  
}
```

Comment: This `b.addActionListener(e -> { System.out.println(); })` is where you specified what your button "will do when pressed" (you specified an action listener). So instead of printing out an empty line when pressed, print the key it is assigned. Like for example: `b.addActionListener(e -> { System.out.print(((JButton)e.getSource()).getText()); });`. However, this will also print "Enter" for example. So these special buttons will have to get special `ActionListener`s since they perform a different action.

Comment: Create a single `Action` that can be shared by all buttons with character text. You can then get the text of the button by using the `getActionCommand()` method of the `ActionEvent`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23375276/attaching-a-single-action-listener-to-all-buttons/23375436#23375436 for a working example.

Comment: Aha that worked! Thanks maloomeister and camickr, as long as I'm able to get that inputted value I can work things from there! I will give them a go