# how to make jbutton immune on second click

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, buttonclick

Im making tic tac toe app, after first click on the button it get either "O" or "X" text and I want to avoid second click, like I want to make it immune to second click

```
if (!pola[i].getText().isEmpty()) {
                pola[i].setEnabled(true);
            }
```

so far I got this,

Comment: The if statement is checking if the text is NOT empty, so maybe you should try to change what you wrote to setEnabled(false)

Comment: yes, i just realised it after I wrote the question, but now I have trouble with checking for draw, im trying to check if all the buttons are enabled and that's gonna equal draw, im thinking of checking every button separately not with for loop

Comment: *I have trouble with checking for draw* You can use an Action shared by all buttons. When the button is clicked you increment a counter to track how many buttons have been clicked and then you disable the button. Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23375276/attaching-a-single-action-listener-to-all-buttons/23375436#23375436 for an example of this approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a boolean `clicked` set it to true when the button is clicked, then in the action listener method check if `!clicked` before you execute the code, or maybe if u want u can do `JFrame.remove(pola[i]);` where JFrame is the frame you are using and if you want it to be interactable again you add it `JFrame.add(pola[i]);`

Comment: thank you for an answer, now I'm struggling with the method that checks if every button is disabled so it gonna return a draw

Comment: well then you have to use the clicked bool in the button class, and in the for loop or for each loop check if `clicked` and make another bool before the loop which is `FoundAButtonNotClicked` and set it to true if there is a button not clicked, at the end if the bool `FoundAButtonNotClicked` is equal to true then there is no draw, if else there is a draw